# Regex - Matching multiple URLs that don't contain specific queries without full path

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match the following domains without the full path.
The issue I'm facing is everything I try also selects the URL's with /product/
Please note that `view=` can equal anything.

Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/`

Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk`

Match: `ourwebsite.co.uk`

Don't Match: `ourwebsite.co.uk/search`

Don't Match: `ourwebsite.co.uk/search?q=test`

Don't Match: `https://ourwebsite.co.uk/product/`

Don't Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/product`

Don't Match: `https://ourwebsite.co.uk/product/product-name`

Don't Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/page`

Don't Match: `https://www.ourwebsitey.co.uk/collection/`

Don't Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/search?q=test*`

Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=cpm&utm_campaign=mof&rs=facebook2_6125507649009_6125720949209_6134410260209&fbclid=IwAR31D2CHnvar5p1Ce0ZoYaHTJRPwaN9aa2q3dsyDu3hGCLkjKNtti3pDm2I`

Don't Match" `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk?view=test&utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=cpm&utm_campaign=mof&rs=facebook2_6125507649009_6125720949209_6134410260209&fbclid=IwAR31D2CHnvar5p1Ce0ZoYaHTJRPwaN9aa2q3dsyDu3hGCLkjKNtti3pDm2I$`

Don't Match: `https://www.ourwebsite.co.uk/?view=testing`

Don't Match: `https://www.google.com`

I've tried a view different option.

See link: https://regex101.com/r/nGtWaC/3

`(.*ourwebsite\.co\.uk)\/(\??)(?!.*[a-z])(?!.*\bview=\b)(.*)`

Everything I try it always selects the full path.

It's for Google Optimise so I'm not sure of the flavour of regex used.

**Updated!**

Solved..

`.*ourwebsite.co\.uk(?:\/\?|\?|\/$|$)(?!.*view=).*`

https://regex101.com/r/nGtWaC/5

Please let me know if this can be done better.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression looks great! I would have also added start and end anchors, maybe with a few more boundaries, somewhat similar to:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?ourwebsite\.co\.uk(?:\/\?|\?|\/$|$)(?!.*view=).*$
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zZtfau/1)